# Generate 10 random 3-letter strings

Tags: python, beginner, strings, random

This is a toy project and I am a beginner in Python.

I need to create 10 random 3-letter strings, where characters are `a` - `z`.

This is my implementation:

```
import random

def random_char():
    return random.randint(97, 122)

three_letter_words = []
for i in range(0, 10):
    three_letter_words.append(chr(random_char()) + chr(random_char()) + chr(random_char()))
```

I really do not like the part where I call `chr(random_char())` 3 times.

How can I improve this to make it more compact and cleaner?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Python 3.6 introduced [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices), which allows you to write this even more succinctly than using `random.choice`:

```
from random import choices
from string import ascii_lowercase

three_letter_words = ["".join(choices(ascii_lowercase, k=3)) for _ in range(10)]
```

Comment: @KorayTugay It is shorter than `["".join(choice(ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(3)) for _ in range(10)]`. IMO this makes it also easier to read. Whether or not it is easier to read than writing out the `for` loop, that depends a bit on how used you are to list comprehensions. I think this one is not yet pushing it so far as to become unreadable.

Comment: I would not recommend doing `from random import choices`. `choices` isn't a comprehensive enough name to stand on its own like that. `random.choices(...)` seems like a much more readable choice (pun intended).

Answer (score 11):

1. a [much more readable way of specifying that character range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2257449/96588):

   ```
   random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
   ```
2. To get a string of `n` characters:

   ```
   ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(n)])
   ```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @l0b0's answer:

To generate cryptographically secure random strings (since this is a toy project, why not use a [CSPRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator)? it's a useful thing to learn):

```py
import string

# only needs to be initialized once
import random
csprng = random.SystemRandom()

# alternatively, the "secrets" module is meant for generating strong csprng numbers
import secrets
csprng = secrets.SystemRandom()

# uses @Graipher's suggestion of .choices()
def random_string(len = 3, charsets = string.ascii_lowercase):
    return ''.join(csprng.choices(charsets, k = len))

three_letter_strings = [random_string() for _ in range(10)]

print(three_letter_strings)

"""
example output:
['ebi', 'hbg', 'hlm', 'rhp', 'eka', 'uja', 'uhi', 'lju', 'vvf', 'qtj']
"""


"""
alternatively, below is likely faster
if you want to do this a lot more than 10 times

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2970789
"""

import itertools

three_letter_strings = [random_string() for _ in itertools.repeat(None, 10)]

print(three_letter_strings)
```

Tested with Python 3.6.5

Comment: You should probably only be using one SystemRandom instance. Also, if you're `extend`ing an empty list with a generator expression you might as well just use a list comprehension. Lastly, your use of `itertools.repeat` just produces the same string 10 times - this may be random in the XKCD sense but probably isn't what OP was after.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen thanks for your feedback, I've edited my answer to include your suggestions (and fixed `itrertools.repeat`, I'd forgotten that it returns the _same_ thing N times, instead of calling it N times).

Comment: Wow, it is actually faster: `%timeit [0 for _ in range(10000000)]`: 325 ms ± 1.38 ms, `%timeit [0 for _ in repeat(None, 10000000)]`: 184 ms ± 1.72 ms. That's a factor 2! (Of course this is only relevant as long as looping dominates the timing and not the execution of the function itself.)